# How to write in pre tag?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests, selenide

I can't write value to field using Selenium .sendKeys. So I use jsCode:

```
element = xpath(//pre[@role='presentation'])


executeJavaScript("arguments[0].value='RESPONSE';", element)
```

and

```
executeJavaScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'RESPONSE')", element);
```

I can't understand why these methods don't work - the test passes but the value is not written to the field

`$("div pre").append("RESPONSE")` - work in devTools

Full html code:

```
<body>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div aria-hidden="true" class="CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper" style="left: -30px;">
            <div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 0px; width: 21px;">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre class="CodeMirror-line" role="presentation"><span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;"><span>​</span></span></pre>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set an attribute named `value` or append an element to the `pre` element?

Comment: @Nils Kähler i am trying to enter text in pre field

Comment: Pls port your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to append to the content of the `pre` tag then use something like `executeJavaScript("arguments[0].append('RESPONSE')", element);`. That should append the response to the element in `arguments[0]`.

If you are trying to set an attribute named `value` to the `pre` element. Then `"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'RESPONSE')"` sets `<pre role='presentation' value="RESPONSE">`.